# Test fragments with Espresso properly while using Navigation UI

Tags: android-fragments, android-espresso, android-testing

I am new to Android Testing (both Unit and Espresso testing). I can set rule

`val activityTestRule = ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity::class.java)`

when I want to create espresso test for MainActivity.

yet, I found this [blog](https://engineering.21buttons.com/how-to-test-fragments-in-isolation-a7435a4cdc92) to do this, but I'm not willing to use external libraries (if possible) for this.

**So, what is the alternative of this for fragment (any kind of) testing?**

But I am using Navigation UI with BottomNavigation, I want to test my fragments which are inside the navigation.
Help me **how can I do that and obviously a proper way?**